# While launching the application on Kony showing "waiting for device"

Tags: temenos-quantum

I developed a simple application on Kony and while launching the application it shows the message "Waiting for device". How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Just "wake" your device by unlocking it, touching its screen or going to home screen.

Answer (score 0):

This message is shown when there are no devices/emulators connected to install the application.

You can check if any device/emulator connected by using the below command in Windows command prompt. [image]

```
adb devices
```

If the above command lists any device/emulator then you wont see the error.

> If the physical device is already connect via USB, the you can check whether the developer option and USB debugging is enabled in you android device.
>   [How to enable developer option?](http://www.greenbot.com/article/2457986/how-to-enable-developer-options-on-your-android-phone-or-tablet.html)

Hope this helps!